# jquery drop down menu links dont work and css

Tags: jquery, css, html, drop-down-menu

New to jquery, html, and css so sorry if this seems simple. I am making a drop down menu using jquery. My links don't work for the drop down menu and when the drop down menu slides down it is cut off and loads a second later? I followed a tutorial where they had no issues but i am receiving a ton. How come my links wont work? Also why is the drop down menu being cut off?

Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#menu ul li").hover(function() {
    $(this).find("ul").stop().slideToggle(400);
   });
 });
</script>
```

CSS

```
nav#menu {
float: right;
margin-right: 150px;
}

nav#menu #menu-nav {
margin: 0;
padding: 0; 
}

nav#menu #menu-nav li {
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
}

nav#menu #menu-nav ul li a{
margin-left: -60px;
background: black;
width: 250px;
}
nav#menu #menu-nav li a {
color: #DE5E60;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 300;
line-height: 60px;
display: block;
padding-right: 1cm;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav#menu #menu-mav ul ul li{
  padding-right: 1cm;
}

nav#menu #menu-nav li a:hover {
color: #FFFFFF;
}


nav#menu ul ul{
position:absolute;
width:400px;
display:none;
}

nav#menu ul ul li{
display:block;
background:#252525;
}
```

html

```
<nav id="nav">
    <nav id="menu">
        <ul id="menu-nav">
            <li><a href="#projects">Home</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="link.html">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 3<a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#services">Services</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="link.html">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="link2.html/">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
   </nav>
```

Comment: I just tried your code in JSFiddle, it seems to work fine. Except the colors..

Comment: Same here, works great for me. Fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/18xtum1v/

Comment: Fix your html code, it is nod valid, nav must be single in whole document, close a tag Home -> Link 3

Comment: @styopdev it's not mandatory for any kind of validation to have only one `nav` per page, this is incorrect information . source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav

Comment: It is semantic mistake - nav cannot contain one other, and nav element is intended only for major block of navigation links.

Comment: @styopdev this is also incorrect, `nav` can contain one another, there are many structure of menu that you can do with more than one `nav`, if you have main menu and then you have sections of sub-menus then it's best to use `navs` because they are major link blocks, please read more before you write about an invalid use of a html tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The links are working as they should do. You didn't close the anchor tag. The drop down list is given 
 **margin-left:-60px**, which is rendered after a pause of about 1 second.

```
nav#menu #menu-nav ul li a{
    //margin-left: -60px;    This is causing the problem
    background: black;
    width: 250px;
}
```

Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/01Loqq3u/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wqj2516y/), your code is working but i think you want the drop down to hide when `mouseout`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#menu ul li").on('mouseover',function() {
    $(this).find("ul").stop().slideToggle(400);
   });

    $("#menu ul li").on('mouseout',function() {
    $(this).find("ul").stop().slideToggle(400);
   });     

 });
```

also check that you have `jQuery` in your `head` tag.

Answer (score 0):

For the slow loading and cut-off, try to remove `margin-left: -60px;`.